# Select text and replace text with text + variable in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, variables, replace, find, notepad++

Apologies, I am quite new to stackoverflow and not sure if this is a suitable question but I have already attempted to find the answer elsewhere

I have the line:

XYZ: "Text"

and am attempting to replace

XYZ: "Text"

with

XYZ: "Text (XYZ)"

is this possible with notepad++, it seems as though I need to select a variable within every line and then replace some text within the line with the text + (variable) can anyone think of a way to do this in Notepad++?

Note: The text on all lines is different and so is XYZ so I need it to be specific to each and every line

Comment: This needs a regular expression. Look at the information available from the [regex] tag just added to the question. (Hover the mouse over the [regex] tag, then click info.)

Comment: can be done easily in sublime if you can use it, pres  `ctrl + H`, select regular expression option on the left hand side and in find what: type `(.*):(.*)"(.*)"` and in replace with textbox type `$1:$2"$3 ($1)"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern for search `(^[^:]*)(:[^"]*"[^"]*)` and `$1$2 \($1\)` for replacement.

<kbd>[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/jX4lQ4/2)</kbd>